# Binding Datagrid to XMLDatasource

Tags: c#, datagrid, xmldatasource

I'm using an XMLDatasource to bind to a data grid.  I'm also using a parameter in my xsl for sorting.  I have everything working but it seems I have to bind twice to my data for it to work when I sort.  Can anyone tell me why?
Here is my webform:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>


    </div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ALT-KEY" HeaderText="ALT-KEY" SortExpression="ALT-KEY" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PARCEL-DISPLAY" HeaderText="PARCEL-DISPLAY" SortExpression="PARCEL-DISPLAY" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="OWNER-NAME" HeaderText="OWNER-NAME" SortExpression="OWNER-NAME" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SITUS" HeaderText="SITUS" SortExpression="SITUS" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PARCEL-DESCRIPTION" HeaderText="PARCEL-DESCRIPTION" SortExpression="PARCEL-DESCRIPTION" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LAST-SALE" HeaderText="LAST-SALE" SortExpression="LAST-SALE" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LAST-PRICE" HeaderText="LAST-PRICE" SortExpression="LAST-PRICE" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" ></asp:XmlDataSource>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my code:
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

```
namespace TestGridSort
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected string sortExpression = "OWNER-NAME";
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                BindData();
            }

        }

        protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            sortExpression = e.SortExpression;
            BindData();
            BindData();
        }
        protected void BindData()
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = "";
            GridView1.DataBind();
            XmlDataSource1.DataFile = "";
            XmlDataSource1.DataBind();
            System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList xslTransform = new System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList();
            XmlDataSource1.TransformArgumentList = null;
            xslTransform.AddParam("sortby", "", sortExpression);
            XmlDataSource1.DataFile = "~/App_Data/Parcels.xml";
            XmlDataSource1.TransformFile = "~/App_Data/xmlfile1.xsl";
            XmlDataSource1.TransformArgumentList = xslTransform;

            GridView1.DataSource = XmlDataSource1;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            BindData();
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<PARCELS REC-COUNT="29" START-COUNT="1" MAXED-TIME="FALSE">
  <PARCEL>
    <ALT-KEY>00792191</ALT-KEY>
    <PARCEL-ID>R01 221 17 3360 0630</PARCEL-ID>
    <PARCEL-DISPLAY>R01 221 17 3360 0630 0150</PARCEL-DISPLAY>
    <OWNER-NAME>POWERS PHYLLIS</OWNER-NAME>
    <OWNER-NAME2></OWNER-NAME2>
    <PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>ROYAL HIGHLANDS UNIT 8</PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>
    <SITUS>11145 THRASHER AVE</SITUS>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-1>11145 THRASHER AVE</MAIL-ADDRESS-1>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-2>WEEKI WACHEE FL 34614-0512</MAIL-ADDRESS-2>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-3>WEEKI WACHEE, FL 34614-0512</MAIL-ADDRESS-3>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-4></MAIL-ADDRESS-4>
    <APPR-VALUE>0000006380</APPR-VALUE>
    <TAX-VALUE>0000006380</TAX-VALUE>
    <BASE-AREA>0000000</BASE-AREA>
    <YEAR-BUILT>0000</YEAR-BUILT>
    <AREA>3360</AREA>
    <LAST-SALE>01/22/10</LAST-SALE>
    <LAST-PRICE>11000</LAST-PRICE>
    <LAST-QUAL>D</LAST-QUAL>
    <LAST-VORI>V</LAST-VORI>
  </PARCEL>
  <PARCEL>
    <ALT-KEY>00233526</ALT-KEY>
    <PARCEL-ID>R32 323 17 5030 0141</PARCEL-ID>
    <PARCEL-DISPLAY>R32 323 17 5030 0141 0070</PARCEL-DISPLAY>
    <OWNER-NAME>LEPP MIRIAM M</OWNER-NAME>
    <OWNER-NAME2>C/O MARIA B KARDOS, POWERS JOSEPH L</OWNER-NAME2>
    <PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>SPRING HILL UNIT 3</PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>
    <SITUS>1498 PIE CT</SITUS>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-1>18906 DVORAK DR</MAIL-ADDRESS-1>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-2>BROOKSVILLE FL 34610-2134</MAIL-ADDRESS-2>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-3>BROOKSVILLE, FL 34610-2134</MAIL-ADDRESS-3>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-4></MAIL-ADDRESS-4>
    <APPR-VALUE>0000067997</APPR-VALUE>
    <TAX-VALUE>0000067997</TAX-VALUE>
    <BASE-AREA>0002000</BASE-AREA>
    <YEAR-BUILT>1983</YEAR-BUILT>
    <AREA>5010</AREA>
    <LAST-SALE>11/03/05</LAST-SALE>
    <LAST-PRICE>237000</LAST-PRICE>
    <LAST-QUAL>Q</LAST-QUAL>
    <LAST-VORI>I</LAST-VORI>
  </PARCEL>
  <PARCEL>
    <ALT-KEY>00322181</ALT-KEY>
    <PARCEL-ID>R32 323 17 5250 1679</PARCEL-ID>
    <PARCEL-DISPLAY>R32 323 17 5250 1679 0090</PARCEL-DISPLAY>
    <OWNER-NAME>JOHNSON KEVIN K, POWERS JAIME L</OWNER-NAME>
    <OWNER-NAME2></OWNER-NAME2>
    <PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>SPRING HILL UNIT 25</PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>
    <SITUS>4420 KEYES AVE</SITUS>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-1>11132 LABRADOR DUCK RD</MAIL-ADDRESS-1>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-2>WEEKI WACHEE FL 34614-4125</MAIL-ADDRESS-2>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-3>WEEKI WACHEE, FL 34614-4125</MAIL-ADDRESS-3>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-4></MAIL-ADDRESS-4>
    <APPR-VALUE>0000038455</APPR-VALUE>
    <TAX-VALUE>0000038455</TAX-VALUE>
    <BASE-AREA>0001344</BASE-AREA>
    <YEAR-BUILT>1973</YEAR-BUILT>
    <AREA>5250</AREA>
    <LAST-SALE>01/10/12</LAST-SALE>
    <LAST-PRICE>20000</LAST-PRICE>
    <LAST-QUAL>D</LAST-QUAL>
    <LAST-VORI>I</LAST-VORI>
  </PARCEL>
  <PARCEL>
    <ALT-KEY>00673738</ALT-KEY>
    <PARCEL-ID>R32 323 17 5180 1251</PARCEL-ID>
    <PARCEL-DISPLAY>R32 323 17 5180 1251 0210</PARCEL-DISPLAY>
    <OWNER-NAME>POWERS JOHN E, POWERS SANDRA L</OWNER-NAME>
    <OWNER-NAME2></OWNER-NAME2>
    <PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>SPRING HILL UNIT 18</PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>
    <SITUS>4487 ABAGAIL DR</SITUS>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-1>4487 ABAGAIL DR</MAIL-ADDRESS-1>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-2>SPRING HILL FL 34608-2702</MAIL-ADDRESS-2>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-3>SPRING HILL, FL 34608-2702</MAIL-ADDRESS-3>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-4></MAIL-ADDRESS-4>
    <APPR-VALUE>0000086402</APPR-VALUE>
    <TAX-VALUE>0000036402</TAX-VALUE>
    <BASE-AREA>0001824</BASE-AREA>
    <YEAR-BUILT>1988</YEAR-BUILT>
    <AREA>5180</AREA>
    <LAST-SALE>07/29/05</LAST-SALE>
    <LAST-PRICE>232500</LAST-PRICE>
    <LAST-QUAL>Q</LAST-QUAL>
    <LAST-VORI>I</LAST-VORI>
  </PARCEL>
  <PARCEL>
    <ALT-KEY>01535253</ALT-KEY>
    <PARCEL-ID>R09 223 18 3602 0390</PARCEL-ID>
    <PARCEL-DISPLAY>R09 223 18 3602 0390 0220</PARCEL-DISPLAY>
    <OWNER-NAME>POWERS CHERYL L</OWNER-NAME>
    <OWNER-NAME2></OWNER-NAME2>
    <PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>STERLING HILL PHASE 1B</PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>
    <SITUS>4583 LARKENHEATH DR</SITUS>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-1>4583 LARKENHEATH DR</MAIL-ADDRESS-1>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-2>SPRING HILL FL 34609</MAIL-ADDRESS-2>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-3>SPRING HILL, FL 34609</MAIL-ADDRESS-3>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-4></MAIL-ADDRESS-4>
    <APPR-VALUE>0000136482</APPR-VALUE>
    <TAX-VALUE>0000136482</TAX-VALUE>
    <BASE-AREA>0003197</BASE-AREA>
    <YEAR-BUILT>2006</YEAR-BUILT>
    <AREA>3601</AREA>
    <LAST-SALE>08/15/13</LAST-SALE>
    <LAST-PRICE>160000</LAST-PRICE>
    <LAST-QUAL>Q</LAST-QUAL>
    <LAST-VORI>I</LAST-VORI>
  </PARCEL>
  <PARCEL>
    <ALT-KEY>01342773</ALT-KEY>
    <PARCEL-ID>R31 223 18 3504 0000</PARCEL-ID>
    <PARCEL-DISPLAY>R31 223 18 3504 0000 1060</PARCEL-DISPLAY>
    <OWNER-NAME>POWERS GERALD M</OWNER-NAME>
    <OWNER-NAME2></OWNER-NAME2>
    <PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>WELLINGTON AT SEVEN HILLS PH 2</PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>
    <SITUS>525 BENT OAK CT</SITUS>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-1>525 BENT OAK CT</MAIL-ADDRESS-1>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-2>SPRING HILL FL 34609-9662</MAIL-ADDRESS-2>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-3>SPRING HILL, FL 34609-9662</MAIL-ADDRESS-3>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-4></MAIL-ADDRESS-4>
    <APPR-VALUE>0000107504</APPR-VALUE>
    <TAX-VALUE>0000052004</TAX-VALUE>
    <BASE-AREA>0001800</BASE-AREA>
    <YEAR-BUILT>1999</YEAR-BUILT>
    <AREA>WELLTN</AREA>
    <LAST-SALE>09/07/99</LAST-SALE>
    <LAST-PRICE>156500</LAST-PRICE>
    <LAST-QUAL>Q</LAST-QUAL>
    <LAST-VORI>I</LAST-VORI>
  </PARCEL>
  <PARCEL>
    <ALT-KEY>00054835</ALT-KEY>
    <PARCEL-ID>R11 123 21 0620 0000</PARCEL-ID>
    <PARCEL-DISPLAY>R11 123 21 0620 0000 2980</PARCEL-DISPLAY>
    <OWNER-NAME>POWERS ROBERT H</OWNER-NAME>
    <OWNER-NAME2></OWNER-NAME2>
    <PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>LAKEWOOD UNIT 3</PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>
    <SITUS>5327 AZALEA CIR</SITUS>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-1>5327 AZALEA CIR</MAIL-ADDRESS-1>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-2>DADE CITY FL 33523</MAIL-ADDRESS-2>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-3>DADE CITY, FL 33523</MAIL-ADDRESS-3>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-4></MAIL-ADDRESS-4>
    <APPR-VALUE>0000066401</APPR-VALUE>
    <TAX-VALUE>0000066401</TAX-VALUE>
    <BASE-AREA>0001844</BASE-AREA>
    <YEAR-BUILT>1979</YEAR-BUILT>
    <AREA>0580</AREA>
    <LAST-SALE>06/28/12</LAST-SALE>
    <LAST-PRICE>63000</LAST-PRICE>
    <LAST-QUAL>D</LAST-QUAL>
    <LAST-VORI>I</LAST-VORI>
  </PARCEL>
  <PARCEL>
    <ALT-KEY>00722445</ALT-KEY>
    <PARCEL-ID>R32 323 17 5220 1522</PARCEL-ID>
    <PARCEL-DISPLAY>R32 323 17 5220 1522 0040</PARCEL-DISPLAY>
    <OWNER-NAME>POWERS CARL T</OWNER-NAME>
    <OWNER-NAME2></OWNER-NAME2>
    <PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>SPRING HILL UNIT 22</PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>
    <SITUS>6291 SUNDAY RD</SITUS>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-1>6291 SUNDAY RD</MAIL-ADDRESS-1>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-2>SPRING HILL FL 34608-1271</MAIL-ADDRESS-2>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-3>SPRING HILL, FL 34608-1271</MAIL-ADDRESS-3>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-4></MAIL-ADDRESS-4>
    <APPR-VALUE>0000069871</APPR-VALUE>
    <TAX-VALUE>0000024500</TAX-VALUE>
    <BASE-AREA>0001654</BASE-AREA>
    <YEAR-BUILT>1989</YEAR-BUILT>
    <AREA>5220</AREA>
    <LAST-SALE>12/01/81</LAST-SALE>
    <LAST-PRICE>4000</LAST-PRICE>
    <LAST-QUAL>Q</LAST-QUAL>
    <LAST-VORI>V</LAST-VORI>
  </PARCEL>
  <PARCEL>
    <ALT-KEY>01589463</ALT-KEY>
    <PARCEL-ID>R35 223 18 3707 0160</PARCEL-ID>
    <PARCEL-DISPLAY>R35 223 18 3707 0160 0100</PARCEL-DISPLAY>
    <OWNER-NAME>POWERS VIRGINIA P</OWNER-NAME>
    <OWNER-NAME2></OWNER-NAME2>
    <PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>TRILLIUM VILLAGE A</PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>
    <SITUS>635 SEA HOLLY DR</SITUS>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-1>635 SEA HOLLY DR</MAIL-ADDRESS-1>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-2>BROOKSVILLE FL 34604</MAIL-ADDRESS-2>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-3>BROOKSVILLE, FL 34604</MAIL-ADDRESS-3>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-4></MAIL-ADDRESS-4>
    <APPR-VALUE>0000089846</APPR-VALUE>
    <TAX-VALUE>0000039846</TAX-VALUE>
    <BASE-AREA>0002207</BASE-AREA>
    <YEAR-BUILT>2007</YEAR-BUILT>
    <AREA>3707</AREA>
    <LAST-SALE>04/16/07</LAST-SALE>
    <LAST-PRICE>181900</LAST-PRICE>
    <LAST-QUAL>Q</LAST-QUAL>
    <LAST-VORI>I</LAST-VORI>
  </PARCEL>
  <PARCEL>
    <ALT-KEY>01009991</ALT-KEY>
    <PARCEL-ID>R21 223 17 6221 0000</PARCEL-ID>
    <PARCEL-DISPLAY>R21 223 17 6221 0000 0370</PARCEL-DISPLAY>
    <OWNER-NAME>POWERS NANCY H, SMITH DARRELL</OWNER-NAME>
    <OWNER-NAME2></OWNER-NAME2>
    <PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>TIMBER PINES TR 22 UNIT 1</PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>
    <SITUS>6393 PLANTATION RD</SITUS>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-1>9388 FRENCH QUARTERS CIR</MAIL-ADDRESS-1>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-2>BROOKSVILLE FL 34613-4212</MAIL-ADDRESS-2>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-3>BROOKSVILLE, FL 34613-4212</MAIL-ADDRESS-3>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-4></MAIL-ADDRESS-4>
    <APPR-VALUE>0000062802</APPR-VALUE>
    <TAX-VALUE>0000062802</TAX-VALUE>
    <BASE-AREA>0001072</BASE-AREA>
    <YEAR-BUILT>1988</YEAR-BUILT>
    <AREA>TP01</AREA>
    <LAST-SALE>05/25/05</LAST-SALE>
    <LAST-PRICE>160000</LAST-PRICE>
    <LAST-QUAL>Q</LAST-QUAL>
    <LAST-VORI>I</LAST-VORI>
  </PARCEL>
  <PARCEL>
    <ALT-KEY>00846124</ALT-KEY>
    <PARCEL-ID>R10 223 17 1423 0008</PARCEL-ID>
    <PARCEL-DISPLAY>R10 223 17 1423 0008 0050</PARCEL-DISPLAY>
    <OWNER-NAME>POWERS PHYLIS</OWNER-NAME>
    <OWNER-NAME2></OWNER-NAME2>
    <PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>BERKELEY MANOR</PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>
    <SITUS>8087 RHANBUOY RD</SITUS>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-1>11145 THRASHER AVE</MAIL-ADDRESS-1>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-2>WEEKI WACHEE FL 34614-0512</MAIL-ADDRESS-2>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-3>WEEKI WACHEE, FL 34614-0512</MAIL-ADDRESS-3>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-4></MAIL-ADDRESS-4>
    <APPR-VALUE>0000111187</APPR-VALUE>
    <TAX-VALUE>0000061187</TAX-VALUE>
    <BASE-AREA>0002766</BASE-AREA>
    <YEAR-BUILT>1990</YEAR-BUILT>
    <AREA>1423</AREA>
    <LAST-SALE>11/01/89</LAST-SALE>
    <LAST-PRICE>18000</LAST-PRICE>
    <LAST-QUAL>Q</LAST-QUAL>
    <LAST-VORI>V</LAST-VORI>
  </PARCEL>
  <PARCEL>
    <ALT-KEY>01113057</ALT-KEY>
    <PARCEL-ID>R26 222 17 3740 0000</PARCEL-ID>
    <PARCEL-DISPLAY>R26 222 17 3740 0000 0930</PARCEL-DISPLAY>
    <OWNER-NAME>POWERS HAROLD E, POWERS EVELYN M</OWNER-NAME>
    <OWNER-NAME2></OWNER-NAME2>
    <PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>VOSS OAK LAKE ESTATES</PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>
    <SITUS>8969 OSTROM WAY</SITUS>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-1>8969 OSTROM WAY</MAIL-ADDRESS-1>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-2>WEEKI WACHEE FL 34613-4481</MAIL-ADDRESS-2>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-3>WEEKI WACHEE, FL 34613-4481</MAIL-ADDRESS-3>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-4></MAIL-ADDRESS-4>
    <APPR-VALUE>0000114243</APPR-VALUE>
    <TAX-VALUE>0000064243</TAX-VALUE>
    <BASE-AREA>0001951</BASE-AREA>
    <YEAR-BUILT>2004</YEAR-BUILT>
    <AREA>3740</AREA>
    <LAST-SALE>08/31/07</LAST-SALE>
    <LAST-PRICE>205000</LAST-PRICE>
    <LAST-QUAL>Q</LAST-QUAL>
    <LAST-VORI>I</LAST-VORI>
  </PARCEL>
  <PARCEL>
    <ALT-KEY>00600184</ALT-KEY>
    <PARCEL-ID>R27 222 18 1474 0570</PARCEL-ID>
    <PARCEL-DISPLAY>R27 222 18 1474 0570 0180</PARCEL-DISPLAY>
    <OWNER-NAME>POWERS WILLIAM J, POWERS MARSHA J</OWNER-NAME>
    <OWNER-NAME2></OWNER-NAME2>
    <PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>BROOKRIDGE COMMUNITY UNIT 4</PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>
    <SITUS>9199 DENMARSH DR</SITUS>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-1>9199 DENMARSH DR</MAIL-ADDRESS-1>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-2>BROOKSVILLE FL 34613</MAIL-ADDRESS-2>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-3>BROOKSVILLE, FL 34613</MAIL-ADDRESS-3>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-4></MAIL-ADDRESS-4>
    <APPR-VALUE>0000043055</APPR-VALUE>
    <TAX-VALUE>0000000000</TAX-VALUE>
    <BASE-AREA>0001404</BASE-AREA>
    <YEAR-BUILT>1988</YEAR-BUILT>
    <AREA>1472</AREA>
    <LAST-SALE>03/21/01</LAST-SALE>
    <LAST-PRICE>66000</LAST-PRICE>
    <LAST-QUAL>Q</LAST-QUAL>
    <LAST-VORI>I</LAST-VORI>
  </PARCEL>
  <PARCEL>
    <ALT-KEY>01195959</ALT-KEY>
    <PARCEL-ID>R13 222 17 1833 0000</PARCEL-ID>
    <PARCEL-DISPLAY>R13 222 17 1833 0000 0980</PARCEL-DISPLAY>
    <OWNER-NAME>POWERS ROBERT D, HERDELL-POWERS NANCY</OWNER-NAME>
    <OWNER-NAME2></OWNER-NAME2>
    <PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>GLEN HILLS VILLAGE</PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>
    <SITUS>9388 FRENCH QUARTERS CIR</SITUS>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-1>9388 FRENCH QUARTERS CIR</MAIL-ADDRESS-1>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-2>BROOKSVILLE FL 34613-4212</MAIL-ADDRESS-2>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-3>BROOKSVILLE, FL 34613-4212</MAIL-ADDRESS-3>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-4></MAIL-ADDRESS-4>
    <APPR-VALUE>0000087904</APPR-VALUE>
    <TAX-VALUE>0000032904</TAX-VALUE>
    <BASE-AREA>0001496</BASE-AREA>
    <YEAR-BUILT>1991</YEAR-BUILT>
    <AREA>GL03</AREA>
    <LAST-SALE>05/24/06</LAST-SALE>
    <LAST-PRICE>220900</LAST-PRICE>
    <LAST-QUAL>Q</LAST-QUAL>
    <LAST-VORI>I</LAST-VORI>
  </PARCEL>
  <PARCEL>
    <ALT-KEY>01708487</ALT-KEY>
    <PARCEL-ID>R10 223 18 3184 0000</PARCEL-ID>
    <PARCEL-DISPLAY>R10 223 18 3184 0000 000B</PARCEL-DISPLAY>
    <OWNER-NAME>POWERSTROKE PROPERTIES LLC</OWNER-NAME>
    <OWNER-NAME2></OWNER-NAME2>
    <PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>POWERSTROKE PLAT</PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>
    <SITUS>ASTAIRE LN</SITUS>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-1>711 S CARSON ST STE 4</MAIL-ADDRESS-1>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-2>CARSON CITY NV 89701-5292</MAIL-ADDRESS-2>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-3>CARSON CITY, NV 89701-5292</MAIL-ADDRESS-3>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-4></MAIL-ADDRESS-4>
    <APPR-VALUE>0000000610</APPR-VALUE>
    <TAX-VALUE>0000000610</TAX-VALUE>
    <BASE-AREA>0000000</BASE-AREA>
    <YEAR-BUILT>0000</YEAR-BUILT>
    <AREA>CPOWL</AREA>
    <LAST-SALE>01/01/08</LAST-SALE>
    <LAST-PRICE>3400000</LAST-PRICE>
    <LAST-QUAL>S</LAST-QUAL>
    <LAST-VORI>V</LAST-VORI>
  </PARCEL>
  <PARCEL>
    <ALT-KEY>01708511</ALT-KEY>
    <PARCEL-ID>R10 223 18 3184 0000</PARCEL-ID>
    <PARCEL-DISPLAY>R10 223 18 3184 0000 0020</PARCEL-DISPLAY>
    <OWNER-NAME>POWERSTROKE PROPERTIES LLC</OWNER-NAME>
    <OWNER-NAME2></OWNER-NAME2>
    <PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>POWERSTROKE PLAT</PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>
    <SITUS>ASTAIRE LN</SITUS>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-1>711 S CARSON ST STE 4</MAIL-ADDRESS-1>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-2>CARSON CITY NV 89701-5292</MAIL-ADDRESS-2>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-3>CARSON CITY, NV 89701-5292</MAIL-ADDRESS-3>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-4></MAIL-ADDRESS-4>
    <APPR-VALUE>0000011967</APPR-VALUE>
    <TAX-VALUE>0000011967</TAX-VALUE>
    <BASE-AREA>0000000</BASE-AREA>
    <YEAR-BUILT>0000</YEAR-BUILT>
    <AREA>PDPSFR</AREA>
    <LAST-SALE>01/01/08</LAST-SALE>
    <LAST-PRICE>3400000</LAST-PRICE>
    <LAST-QUAL>S</LAST-QUAL>
    <LAST-VORI>V</LAST-VORI>
  </PARCEL>
  <PARCEL>
    <ALT-KEY>01492673</ALT-KEY>
    <PARCEL-ID>R10 223 18 3184 0000</PARCEL-ID>
    <PARCEL-DISPLAY>R10 223 18 3184 0000 000A</PARCEL-DISPLAY>
    <OWNER-NAME>POWERSTROKE PROPERTIES LLC</OWNER-NAME>
    <OWNER-NAME2></OWNER-NAME2>
    <PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>POWERSTROKE PLAT</PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>
    <SITUS>ASTAIRE LN</SITUS>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-1>711 S CARSON ST STE 4</MAIL-ADDRESS-1>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-2>CARSON CITY NV 89701-5292</MAIL-ADDRESS-2>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-3>CARSON CITY, NV 89701-5292</MAIL-ADDRESS-3>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-4></MAIL-ADDRESS-4>
    <APPR-VALUE>0000002000</APPR-VALUE>
    <TAX-VALUE>0000002000</TAX-VALUE>
    <BASE-AREA>0000000</BASE-AREA>
    <YEAR-BUILT>0000</YEAR-BUILT>
    <AREA>CPOWL</AREA>
    <LAST-SALE>09/29/06</LAST-SALE>
    <LAST-PRICE>3400000</LAST-PRICE>
    <LAST-QUAL>Q</LAST-QUAL>
    <LAST-VORI>V</LAST-VORI>
  </PARCEL>
  <PARCEL>
    <ALT-KEY>00202453</ALT-KEY>
    <PARCEL-ID>R17 223 19 1780 0260</PARCEL-ID>
    <PARCEL-DISPLAY>R17 223 19 1780 0260 0030</PARCEL-DISPLAY>
    <OWNER-NAME>POWERS DONN Q</OWNER-NAME>
    <OWNER-NAME2></OWNER-NAME2>
    <PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>GARDEN GROVE BLK 26</PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>
    <SITUS>BROAD ST</SITUS>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-1>19 REDBAY CT E</MAIL-ADDRESS-1>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-2>HOMOSASSA FL 34446-5121</MAIL-ADDRESS-2>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-3>HOMOSASSA, FL 34446-5121</MAIL-ADDRESS-3>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-4></MAIL-ADDRESS-4>
    <APPR-VALUE>0000004950</APPR-VALUE>
    <TAX-VALUE>0000004950</TAX-VALUE>
    <BASE-AREA>0000000</BASE-AREA>
    <YEAR-BUILT>0000</YEAR-BUILT>
    <AREA>C411</AREA>
    <LAST-SALE></LAST-SALE>
    <LAST-PRICE>0000000000</LAST-PRICE>
    <LAST-QUAL></LAST-QUAL>
    <LAST-VORI></LAST-VORI>
  </PARCEL>
  <PARCEL>
    <ALT-KEY>00168026</ALT-KEY>
    <PARCEL-ID>R13 223 16 2350 1080</PARCEL-ID>
    <PARCEL-DISPLAY>R13 223 16 2350 1080 0250</PARCEL-DISPLAY>
    <OWNER-NAME>POWERS JANICE</OWNER-NAME>
    <OWNER-NAME2></OWNER-NAME2>
    <PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>HERNANDO BEACH UNIT 12</PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>
    <SITUS>CRAPE MYRTLE DR</SITUS>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-1>1408 SE 5TH AVE</MAIL-ADDRESS-1>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-2>CRYSTAL RIVER FL 34429-4928</MAIL-ADDRESS-2>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-3>CRYSTAL RIVER, FL 34429-4928</MAIL-ADDRESS-3>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-4></MAIL-ADDRESS-4>
    <APPR-VALUE>0000029227</APPR-VALUE>
    <TAX-VALUE>0000029227</TAX-VALUE>
    <BASE-AREA>0000000</BASE-AREA>
    <YEAR-BUILT>0000</YEAR-BUILT>
    <AREA>2350</AREA>
    <LAST-SALE>06/06/03</LAST-SALE>
    <LAST-PRICE>55000</LAST-PRICE>
    <LAST-QUAL>Q</LAST-QUAL>
    <LAST-VORI>V</LAST-VORI>
  </PARCEL>
  <PARCEL>
    <ALT-KEY>00723872</ALT-KEY>
    <PARCEL-ID>R01 221 17 3340 0348</PARCEL-ID>
    <PARCEL-DISPLAY>R01 221 17 3340 0348 0120</PARCEL-DISPLAY>
    <OWNER-NAME>POWERS JAMES J, POWERS PHYLLIS M</OWNER-NAME>
    <OWNER-NAME2></OWNER-NAME2>
    <PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>ROYAL HIGHLANDS UNIT 5</PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>
    <SITUS>FLICKER RD</SITUS>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-1>8087 RHANBUOY RD</MAIL-ADDRESS-1>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-2>SPRING HILL FL 34606-1954</MAIL-ADDRESS-2>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-3>SPRING HILL, FL 34606-1954</MAIL-ADDRESS-3>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-4></MAIL-ADDRESS-4>
    <APPR-VALUE>0000004000</APPR-VALUE>
    <TAX-VALUE>0000004000</TAX-VALUE>
    <BASE-AREA>0000000</BASE-AREA>
    <YEAR-BUILT>0000</YEAR-BUILT>
    <AREA>3340</AREA>
    <LAST-SALE>07/01/05</LAST-SALE>
    <LAST-PRICE>42000</LAST-PRICE>
    <LAST-QUAL>Q</LAST-QUAL>
    <LAST-VORI>V</LAST-VORI>
  </PARCEL>
  <PARCEL>
    <ALT-KEY>00062648</ALT-KEY>
    <PARCEL-ID>R01 221 17 3290 0092</PARCEL-ID>
    <PARCEL-DISPLAY>R01 221 17 3290 0092 0010</PARCEL-DISPLAY>
    <OWNER-NAME>POWERS HAROLD E, POWERS EVELYN</OWNER-NAME>
    <OWNER-NAME2></OWNER-NAME2>
    <PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>ROYAL HIGHLANDS</PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>
    <SITUS>FLORIDA WREN AVE</SITUS>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-1>8969 OSTROM WAY</MAIL-ADDRESS-1>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-2>WEEKI WACHEE FL 34613</MAIL-ADDRESS-2>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-3>WEEKI WACHEE, FL 34613</MAIL-ADDRESS-3>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-4></MAIL-ADDRESS-4>
    <APPR-VALUE>0000004350</APPR-VALUE>
    <TAX-VALUE>0000004350</TAX-VALUE>
    <BASE-AREA>0000000</BASE-AREA>
    <YEAR-BUILT>0000</YEAR-BUILT>
    <AREA>3290</AREA>
    <LAST-SALE>03/26/04</LAST-SALE>
    <LAST-PRICE>9000</LAST-PRICE>
    <LAST-QUAL>Q</LAST-QUAL>
    <LAST-VORI>V</LAST-VORI>
  </PARCEL>
  <PARCEL>
    <ALT-KEY>00609540</ALT-KEY>
    <PARCEL-ID>R01 221 17 3280 0012</PARCEL-ID>
    <PARCEL-DISPLAY>R01 221 17 3280 0012 0120</PARCEL-DISPLAY>
    <OWNER-NAME>POWERS BRENDA</OWNER-NAME>
    <OWNER-NAME2></OWNER-NAME2>
    <PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>ROYAL HIGHLANDS UNIT 1</PARCEL-DESCRIPTION>
    <SITUS>YELLOWTHROAT AVE</SITUS>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-1>269 SPRING COLONY CIR SPT 142</MAIL-ADDRESS-1>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-2>ALTAMONTE SPRINGS FL 32714-5165</MAIL-ADDRESS-2>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-3>ALTAMONTE SPRINGS, FL 32714-5165</MAIL-ADDRESS-3>
    <MAIL-ADDRESS-4></MAIL-ADDRESS-4>
    <APPR-VALUE>0000004026</APPR-VALUE>
    <TAX-VALUE>0000004026</TAX-VALUE>
    <BASE-AREA>0000000</BASE-AREA>
    <YEAR-BUILT>0000</YEAR-BUILT>
    <AREA>3280</AREA>
    <LAST-SALE>07/01/86</LAST-SALE>
    <LAST-PRICE>10200</LAST-PRICE>
    <LAST-QUAL>D</LAST-QUAL>
    <LAST-VORI>V</LAST-VORI>
  </PARCEL>
</PARCELS>
```

And here is my xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
   version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml"
      omit-xml-declaration="yes"
      indent="yes"
      standalone="yes" />
  <xsl:param name="sortby" select="'OWNER-NAME'"/>
  <xsl:param name="order" select="'ascending'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="PARCELS">
      <xsl:element name="PARCELS">
        <xsl:for-each select="PARCEL">
          <xsl:sort select="*[name()=$sortby]"/>
          <xsl:element name="PARCEL">
            <xsl:attribute name="ALT-KEY">
              <xsl:value-of select="ALT-KEY"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="PARCEL-DISPLAY">
              <xsl:value-of select="PARCEL-DISPLAY"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="OWNER-NAME">
              <xsl:value-of select="OWNER-NAME"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="SITUS">
              <xsl:value-of select="SITUS"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="PARCEL-DESCRIPTION">
              <xsl:value-of select="PARCEL-DESCRIPTION"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="LAST-SALE">
              <xsl:value-of select="LAST-SALE"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="LAST-PRICE">
              <xsl:value-of select='format-number(LAST-PRICE,"$###,###,###,###")'/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add XPath="/Parcels/Parcel" to your GridView, see below:

`<asp:GridView XPath="/Parcels/Parcel" ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" >`